# KendoUI Grid MemberType empty when filter requested

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

We're using a KendoUI Grid control. We use a Kendo DataSource to request some datas to our Web API :

```
this.gridDatasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read:
                {
                    url: url,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'JSON'
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "Data", // records are returned in the "data" field of the response
                total: "Total", // total number of records is in the "total" field of the response
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        name : { type: "string" }
                    },
                }
            },
```

As you can see, type for my field "name" is correctly defined. When our Grid sends an Ajax request to my API, MemberType of the FilterDescriptor object sent by Kendo is empty. Any ideas ?

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever find out how to get that property to populate?

Comment: We don't use Kendo MVC server-side anymore, we use pur REST API from Kendo Angular component, sorry ...